# logname unset with input redirection (stdin)

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix, command-line

For linux why when providing stdin (input redirection) to **logname** it is not able to determine the user?

```
@> echo `logname`
<username>
@> echo `logname` < /dev/null
logname: no login name
@> echo `logname` < /dev/tty
logname: no login name
```

Moverover this does not seem to affect **whoami**.

```
@> echo `whoami`
<username>
@> echo `whoami` < /dev/null
<username>
```

**Edit:** Adding OS versions (tested it on multiple different Linux machines).

```
@> uname -a
Linux <machine1> 2.6.18-164.el5 #1 SMP Tue Aug 18 15:51:48 EDT 2009 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
@> uname -a
Linux <machine2> 2.6.18-238.el5 #1 SMP Sun Dec 19 14:22:44 EST 2010 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
@> uname -a
Linux <machine3> 3.0.13-0.27-default #1 SMP Wed Feb 15 13:33:49 UTC 2012 (d73692b) x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Comment: Cannot reproduce this behaviour.

Comment: `logname` is only supposed to read `/var/run/utmp`. Redirecting `stdin` should have no effect at all.

Comment: Can you provide your shell and linux os vesrion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On Unix/Linux systems, you can have multiple users logged in through different windows, `ssh` sessions etc. Each currently logged in user may or may not have a `tty` associated with the session. If there is a `tty` session allocated for a user, the association between `tty` and the user logged in on it is stored in the systems `utmp` file (the path may vary). `logname` wants to first see what `tty` you are on, then look up the associated record in the `utmp` file to see who you are. When you do `logname < /dev/null`, `logname` is disassociated from your `tty`, and so fails to find out which record it needs to lookup, which is why it reports "no login name".